# Cannot show cherrypy´s "access.log" in the browser

Tags: python, cherrypy

i try to serve the "access.log" in the browser but i get the error:

"The requested resource returned more bytes than the declared Content-Length."

For the "error.log" it works, i serve both as static files and make a link to it.
I guess the "access.log" is updated by using the link for it and the size does not fit the size cherrypy expected to serve the file.

How can i slove this without reading the "access.log" and show it as html-page?

sincerly

```
         'log.access_file': 'fax_print_access.txt',
         'log.error_file': 'fax_print_error.txt',

      '/fax_print_error.txt':
      {'tools.staticfile.on': True,
       'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fax_print_error.txt'),
      },
      '/fax_print_access.txt':
      {'tools.staticfile.on': True,
       'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fax_print_access.txt'),
      },
```

Comment: Probably because it gets updated after the `Content-Length` is set but before it's sent to the browser.

Comment: You may create a generator handler yielding this file line by line.

Comment: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=stream#streaming-the-response-body

Comment: You might try adding `'response.stream': True`, but I'm not sure whether it works with static

Comment: I guess i have to read the log and output it as html. Still wondering that i cant find other post with the same problem.

Comment: You may read log, but output it as is using generator